# Removing white space and newlines from a database

Tags: php, mysql, string

Here's how the data in my database looks like:

```
&nbsp;
&nbsp;
[translate lang=ar]
```

What I'm trying to do is to get this data from the database starting with [translate lang=ar and do a substr on it to start from ar (after the equal sign).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(TRIM(someColumn), ']', 1), '=', -1) 'lang' FROM someTable
```